# SQL Update in VB.Net using ExecuteNonScalar returns no result OR Error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

I'm writing a piece of software for an old teacher, and I'm having a problem with a SQL statement. I have an UPDATE statement that updates my database using SQL Parameters that get there value from a DGV cell. I've stepped through my code and every parameter pulls the correct value before the statement is ran. But as I execute the statement, no changes are made but there's also no error. Can anyone lend a hand?

```
Dim CourseID As Integer
Dim ASIdentifier As String = "AS Politics"
Dim A2Identifier As String = "A2 Politics"
Dim CourseIdentifier As String

Dim sqlStudents As String = "SELECT tblMembers.UserID, tblMembers.Username, tblMembers.Email, tblCourse.CourseTitle FROM tblMembers INNER JOIN tblCourse ON tblMembers.CourseID = tblCourse.CourseID"

Dim sqlUpdateAS As String = "UPDATE tblMembers SET Username = @Username, Email = @Email, CourseID = '" & CourseID & "' FROM dbo.tblMembers INNER JOIN dbo.tblCourse ON tblMembers.CourseID = tblCourse.CourseID WHERE tblCourse.CourseTitle = '" & CourseIdentifier & "'  AND UserID= @UserID"

Dim connString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\WindowsApplication6\dbMembers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

Dim dbConn As New SqlConnection(connString)



Private Sub btnUpdateTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateTable.Click
    Dim numOfRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim changes As Integer

    numOfRows = dgvStudents.Rows.Count()

    Dim sqlUpdateASCmd As New SqlCommand(sqlUpdateAS, dbConn)

    sqlUpdateASCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
    sqlUpdateASCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
    sqlUpdateASCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int))

    Do Until i = numOfRows - 1

        sqlUpdateASCmd.Parameters("@Username").Value = (dgvStudents.Item(1, i).Value)
        sqlUpdateASCmd.Parameters("@Email").Value = (dgvStudents.Item(2, i).Value)
        sqlUpdateASCmd.Parameters("@UserID").Value = (dgvStudents.Item(0, i).Value)

        If (dgvStudents.Item(3, i).Value) = ASIdentifier Then

            CourseID = 1
            CourseIdentifier = ASIdentifier

            Try
                dbConn.Open()
                changes = sqlUpdateASCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                dbConn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database.", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try

            i += 1

        ElseIf (dgvStudents.Item(3, i).Value) = A2Identifier Then

            CourseID = 2
            CourseIdentifier = A2Identifier

            Try
                dbConn.Open()
                changes = sqlUpdateASCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                dbConn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database.", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
            i += 1

        End If

    Loop
    MsgBox("Database Updated. " & changes & " changes made.")

End Sub
```

Comment: You set the value for courseID after you have set the text of the command. The text in the command doens't update as you seems to think.

Comment: ...and you may be  looping thru 1 too many rows

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection